# Google Sheets Macro for deleting columns in specific tabs based on header

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I wrote a macro that creates sheet tabs and populates them based on specific criteria.  For example, if I want to isolate rows indicating Closed Won, and move them to a new tab.  I will run this function on my main tab called 'data' and create a new tab called 'Closed Won'.

This new tab will duplicate the same header as in 'data', and then it will populate with all rows with "Closed Won" in column L.

However, this new tab has more data than I need.  I want to delete specific columns IF they have a column name AND tab name (so it does not delete the columns in my original data tab).

I am having trouble with the IF.  Can someone help with a simple script that I can add to the end of the original function?

```
function closed_won() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('1:1').activate();
  spreadsheet.insertSheet(1);
  spreadsheet.getRange('1:1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setName('closed_won');
  spreadsheet.getRange('data!1:1').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('data');
  var testrange = sheet.getRange('L:L');
  var testvalue = (testrange.getValues());
  var csh = ss.getSheetByName('closed_won');
  var data = [];
  var j =[];
    for (i=0; i<testvalue.length;i++) {
      if ( testvalue[i] == 'Closed Won') {
  data.push.apply(data,sheet.getRange(i+1,1,1,25).getValues());
  j.push(i);
 }
 }
csh.getRange(csh.getLastRow()+1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
// THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO ADD THE DELETE COLUMN CODE
}
```

Comment: Welcome. Please share a copy of your spreadsheet excluding any private or confidential information, but including an example of a successful outcome. May I try to clarify, please correct me if I am wrong. You have a sheet, "Closed Won"; the header of some columns on the sheet have the same name as other, existing sheets; you wish to delete any such columns from "Closed Won". Of course you don't wish to delete any column (such as Column L, "Closed Won") that is on a sheet of the same name  (such as "Closed Won").

Answer (score 0):

You want to delete columns where the header name matches a sheet name - though obviously not on the current sheet.

The process is:

1. get the sheets and their names; save them in an array
2. get the header row. This will be a 2D array, so "flatten" it to 1D for easier matching
3. loop through the headers and look for a match with sheet names. The code uses `indexOf` for this.

   3.1 when you find a match of header name and column name, make sure that its not the match for the current sheet
   3.2. create an array of the column numbers to be deleted.
4. After the loop, reverse the order of the array so that the "highest" to-be-deleted column numbers are listed first.
5. Loop through the to-be-deleted column numbers, and delete the columns

---

```
function SO5819343001() {

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  // get sheets names
  var thesheets = [];
  var sheets = spreadsheet.getSheets();
  if (sheets.length > 1) {
    for (var i=0; i<sheets.length;i++){
      thesheets.push(sheets[i].getName());
    }
  }


  // move to 'closed_won'
  var csh = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('closed_won');


  // get the headers
  //last column for range
  var cshLC = csh.getLastColumn();
  var headers = csh.getRange(1,1,1,cshLC).getValues();

  // flatten headers from 2D to 1D
  var flatheaders = headers.reduce(function(a, b){return a.concat(b);});  
  // Logger.log(flatheaders); DEBUG

  // create variables for loop
  var cshname = csh.getName();
  var deletions = [];

  // loop through the headers and compare to sheet names
  for (var h = 0; h<cshLC;h++){

    var idx = thesheets.indexOf(flatheaders[h]);
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: h = "+h+", header = "+flatheaders[h]+", match = "+idx)

    // is this a match?
    if (idx !=-1){
      // found a match for column name and sheet name

      // make sure it is not this sheet
      if (flatheaders[h] != cshname){

        // Logger.log("DEBUG: the match is NOT on this sheet. Proceeding")
        // create an array of the column numbers to be deleted
        deletions.push(h+1);
      }
      else{
      Logger.log("the match IS on this sheet. Abort.")
      }

    }

  }
  // Logger.log(deletions); DEBUG
  // reverse the column order
  var rev_deletions = deletions.reverse();
  // Logger.log(rev_deletions); // DEBUG

  // loop through the 'to-be-deleted' columns and delete them
  for (d = 0;d<deletions.length;d++){
    csh.deleteColumn(rev_deletions[d]);
  }

}
```